# If a sequence is in an open interval, is its limit in that interval?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have $(U_n)$ converges and its in some interval, can we say that $l = \lim U_n$  is in that interval?
I know that in this case that $\lim U_n = \sup \{U_n\}$ but it appears that the supremum of $U_n$ isn't necessarily mean that it's going to be in the interval $(a,b)$ or ?

Because

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $\frac{1}{n}\in (0,1), n>1$